# Can't find types in ResourceDictionary when loading with XamlReader.Load

Tags: wpf

In my prism module, I have the following code snippet:

```
        using (var manifestResourceStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyAssembly.CaseHost.ViewModelDataTemplates.xaml"))
        {
            ParserContext context = new ParserContext();
            context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("local", "clr-namespace:MyAssembly.CaseHost");
            var resourceDictionary = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(manifestResourceStream, context);
            _resourceRegistry.Add(resourceDictionary);
        }
```

I'm basically trying to load up this very simple ResourceDictionary:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PlayPauseViewModel}">
    <Label>Look mom!</Label>
</DataTemplate>
```

This gives me the following exception:

Type reference cannot find public type named 'PlayPauseViewModel'.

This is a cpp/winforms/wpf application beast, so I can't use URI's. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it!

The problem was how the namespace was specified in the DataTemplate:

Standard definition (did not work):

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:<Namespace>"
```

More explicit definition (worked!)

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:<Namespace>;assembly=<assembly>"
```

Replace <> with namespace and assembly.

Answer (score 2):

But what to do if you have this code in the same assembly? 
You are not allowed to use

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:<Namespace>;assembly=<assembly>"
```

there?

Comment: My datatemplate is placed in the same assembly as the viewmodels it refers to, so it should work.